# Perl/Awk Dollar sign

Tags: perl

I have a variable like

```
var=abcd cdef$0ghkl
```

I am trying to use awk inside perl and wrote a code like

```
$Var1=`echo "$var"|awk -F '{print \$1}'`;
$Var2=`echo "$var"|awk -F '{print \$2}'`;
```

But `$0` is pretended as sh and output getting as `cdefshghkl`.. How can we print `$0` instead of sh?

Answer (score 3):

You can access environment variables inside perl via the `%ENV` hash, and you do not need awk to split strings for you by calling the shell. Perl is perfectly capable of splitting strings.

```
my ($var1, $var2) = split ' ', $ENV{var};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response..split worked pefectly fine

Comment: `perl` was basically invented because people got fed up with shelling out to `awk`, `sed`, `cut` and `grep`...

Comment: @Kris If this answer solved your problem, you should click the checkmark and make it the accepted answer.